# Using chain rule for partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If $u=f(x,y)$, where $x=e^{5s}\cos(2t)$ and $y=e^{5s}\sin(2t)$, I must find $g(s,t)$ and $h(s,t)$ in the following equation: $$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2=g(s,t)\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)^2+h(s,t)\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2$$

We observe that $x_s=5x, x_t=-2y, y_s=5y, y_t=2x$, $x^2+y^2=e^{10s}$. Then: $$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)=u_s=5xu_x+5yu_y$$ $$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)=u_t=-2yu_x+2xu_y$$

Then, adding the square of these quantities: $$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2=u_s^2+u_t^2=(25u_x^2x^2+50xyu_xu_y+25u_y^2y^2)+(4u_x^2y^2-8xyu_xu_y+4u_y^2x^2)$$ I have seen this question commonly with $x=e^s\cos(t)$ and $y=e^s\sin(t)$, in which case, the "$xyu_xu_y$" quantities cancel out neatly at the end, and substituting $x^2+y^2$, it is easy to obtain the other side of the equation. But in this case, I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should plug in your calculated values for $u_s, u_t$.  Now you need to solve for
$\begin{array}{lll}u_x^2+u_y^2 &= & 25g(s,t)(xu_x + yu_y)^2 + 4h(s,t)(-yu_x + xu_y)^2\\ &= & u_x^2 (25x^2 g(s,t) + 4y^2h(s,t)) \\
& &+ u_xu_y(50xyg(s,t) - 8xyh(s,t)) \\
& &+ u_y^2(25y^2g(x,t) + 4x^2h(s,t))
\end{array} 
$.

Now you can see that the $u_xu_y$ terms cancel as desired only if $g(s,t) = (4/25)h(s,t)$.  From there finding a solution should be straightforward.